# Merging two vectors with fill-pointer in the resulting vector

Tags: vector, merge, common-lisp, fill-pointer

I have two vectors with fill-pointers. I need to `merge` these vectors and have as a result a new vector that still has a fill-pointer.

```lisp
(defparameter *a* (make-array 3 :fill-pointer 3
                                :initial-contents '(1 3 5)))
(defparameter *b* (make-array 3 :fill-pointer 3
                                :initial-contents '(0 2 4)))
(type-of *a*)
;;=> (VECTOR T 6)

;; Pushing new elements works as intended.
(vector-push-extend 7 *a*)
(vector-push-extend 6 *b*)
;; Now we create a new vector by merging *a* and *b*.
(defparameter *c* (merge 'vector *a* *b* #'<))
;;=> #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
(type-of *c*)
;;=> (SIMPLE-VECTOR 8)

;; The type of this new vector does not allow pushing elements.
(vector-push-extend 8 *c*)

;; The value
;;   #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
;; is not of type
;;   (AND VECTOR (NOT SIMPLE-ARRAY))
;;    [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

I can't seem to find a type to specify to [merge](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_merge.htm) so that the result will have a fill-pointer. I guess the obvious workarounds would be either:

- Write a `merge` function myself that declares a new vector and performs the insertions in the correct order.
- Copy the result into another vector with a fill-pointer.

Of course both workarounds are pretty unsatisfactory if there is a way to do this using `merge` from the standard.

Comment: What's wrong with `(defparameter *d* (make-array (length *c*) :fill-pointer (length *c*) :initial-contents *c*))`? `(fill-pointer *d*) => 8`

Comment: I did not think of that. Does it involve an additional copy operation of all the cells in the array? I'm testing this.

Comment: @ThomasHoullier: yes, this creates a new vector and copies data there.

Comment: Alright, I wrote a quick test and indeed the operation of declaring this new vector has an execution time that depends linearly on the size of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is no easy way to get [`merge`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_merge.htm)
return a [`vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_vector.htm) with a
fill-pointer.

You can, however, *displace* your vector to the result:

```lisp
(defparameter *c* (merge '(vector t) *a* *b* #'<))
(type-of *c*)
==> (SIMPLE-VECTOR 8)
(defparameter *d* (make-array (length *c*) :displaced-to *c* :fill-pointer t))
(type-of *d*)
==> (VECTOR T 8)
*d*
==> #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
(array-displacement *d*)
==> #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7); 0
(vector-push-extend 17 *d*)
==> 8
*d*
==> #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 17)
```

So far so good, right?

Nope, not so fast:

```lisp
(array-displacement *d*)
==> NIL; 0
```

When we called [`vector-push-extend`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_vec_ps.htm)
on `*d*`, it was converted from a displaced array to a normal one
because the underlying [`simple-vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_smp_ve.htm)
cannot be extended.

You might actually consider using lists instead of arrays if you want to
use `merge` because it is much more efficient on lists (reuses the
structure).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, on my end the first call to a `vector-push-extend` comes at a tremendous cost. I guess I must switch to lists or do without `merge` as you suggested.